# Why doesn't SFML require OpenGL libraries?

Tags: c++, libraries

I know that SFML is a 2D OpenGL library, but why does programs using SFML not require `opengl32.dll` or `glew.dll`?

I created library.lib and library.dll, which use external functions from GLEW and FreeGLUT. Then, I created `test_library.exe` and linked my library to this program.
After compiling (successfully) I realized that this program requires some DLLs from my library.

How do I use external symbols from missing DLLs just like SFML?

Comment: `opengl32.dll` is a Windows component and does not need to be redistributed. And most OpenGL functions are loaded with `wglGetProcAddress`. The functions themselves are graphics card driver components, they are not in a DLL that you need to redistribute. What glew does is automate all the calls to `wglGetProcAddress`, but nothing stops a program (like SFML) from doing the work itself.

Comment: Thanks, useful information.